# wsl: git pull temporarily thinks there are local changes

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a git repo checked out under the windows subsystem for linux (WSL).  The repo was previously created on the filesystem using git for windows, and I'm in the habit of accessing it from both windows and WSL.

I periodically sync up from an alternate remote (git pull alt_remote master) in WSL.  Normally this should trigger a merge commit, the editor opens, I save the message and the merge completes.

Instead what happens is the pull lists some subset of files in the pull, suggesting that I have local changes that will be clobbered, and I need to commit or stash them. I have made no changes to these files.

I try the same command again a few seconds later and it succeeds as if there was no issue.

I suspect there is some issue with newline policies and how git modifies files to match config settings.  Is there a recommended way I can configure git on either/both Windows/WSL so they can play nice with each other, and I don't encounter these failures?  I have set core.autocrlf=true.

Comment: My guess—but it is only a guess since I don't use Windows and hence don't need WSL—is that Windows' stat data appears different from WSL's stat data. That makes the stat data in the Git index "wrong" from the point of view of the other subsystem. If so, forcibly refreshing the index would also work around the problem. (`rm .git/index; git reset` will do that, but note that this is terribly ugly.)

Comment: My observation about this is that it's filesystem-related, but beyond that I'm not sure exactly what is going on.  After the first git pull fails, if I run git pull immediately after, I get the same error but for a smaller number of files, and then running it again succeeds.  So, some state on the filesystem seems to be playing catch-up.  It seems like this isn't really a question for SO but an issue to open with the WSL or git folks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `core.autocrlf input`.

From https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

> If you’re on a Linux or macOS system that uses LF line endings, then you don’t want Git to automatically convert them when you check out files; however, if a file with CRLF endings accidentally gets introduced, then you may want Git to fix it. You can tell Git to convert CRLF to LF on commit but not the other way around by setting core.autocrlf to input:
>
> ```sh
> $ git config --global core.autocrlf input
> ```